# 'just because some moistened bint lobbed a scimitar at me' meaning

Tags: meaning

The following quote is from Monty Python and the Holy Grail (1975) between Denis and King Arthur.

> [Oh but if I went 'round sayin' I was Emperor, just because some moistened bint lobbed a scimitar at me, they'd put me away.](http://web.archive.org/web/20170727153558/http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0091184/quotes)

I kind of understand the words one by one, but I fail getting the whole statement. For instance, ['moistened bint'](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Moisten%20Bint) seems to be a sexist word for a woman and scimitar is a kind of sword. Is it a royal tradition or something that Dennis is mocking? What does 'lobbed a scimitar at me' mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a reference to the [Lady of the Lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady_of_the_Lake) giving King Arthur, [Excalibur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excalibur). Took me a while to figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

King Arthur is claiming to be king on the grounds that a lady came out of a lake and threw him a sword. Denis is basically saying that if he made a similar claim, people would think he was mad. He changes a few words for comic effect - king becomes emperor, sword becomes scimitar and lady of the lake becomes moistened bint.

Answer (score 1):

Bint is Arabic for daughter, but was used in England somewhat derogatorily, as tart is used a few moments later. Scimitar is a Middle Eastern sword to make the quip coherent. Well written comedy.

Comment: This doesn' answer the question at all, it only helps translating 2 words one of which the OP already knew the meaning...

Answer (score 1):

"The Lady of the Lake [...] held aloft Excalibur, THAT is WHY I am YOUR KING!"
Denis/Dennis is basically saying that the idea that Arthur son of Uther Pendragon was the King of England because a sword rose up from a lake is absurd. Moistened Bint is a dig at the legendary Lady Of The Lake, and the Scimitar is in place of Excalibur. So basically he is mocking Arthur, or at least saying that simply owning Excalibur is no reason for him to be King of all England.